# Unknown 80s/90s supernatural thriller movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie many years ago (25+) and haven't found it again since. US made movie.

It starts with a woman walking through a parking lot and she's being harassed by some guy and a stranger steps in and rescues her. The stranger protects her throughout the movie from whoever is after her and it doesn't end well for him. I think at some point they go to one of his friends who is a bit of a military nut with a bunker and loads of weapons and some supernatural force destroys the bunker. The final scene is a repeat of the first, she is being harassed by same dude and a new stranger comes to the rescue.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Please check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking questions to see if you recall any more details to [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spellbinder: a 1988 American witchcraft-themed thriller film starring Timothy Daly and Kelly Preston.  The man (Daly) rescues the woman (Preston) from her 'abusive' boyfriend in a parking lot.  Daly then does try to protect Preston from the coven chasing her.  Daly is a lawyer who represents the military nut who he and his friend think the woman will be safe with - they're wrong and the place is destroyed by the witches. It's all a setup in the end - she's also a witch who needs a willing volunteer for a Satanic sacrifice. It doesn't go well at all for Daly who is sacrificed to Satan on a beach. Preston goes on to repeat the process again with her 'abusive' boyfriend on the next unsuspecting victim. Also Daly's friend (played by Rick Rossovich) is in on it too, leading men to 'save' the woman.  Saw it just recently on Epix channel.
[image]